# Сovering a rectangle

Tags: combinatorics

This is a rectangle $X × Y$ for $X = 2, Y = 2$:

```
00
00
```

This is $2^{XY}$ of its varieties:

```
00 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11
00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11
+  -  -  +  -  +  -  -  -  -  +  -  +  -  -  +
```

How to find the number of rectangles that can be covered completely?

$X \in [3, 6]$; $Y \in [1, 1000]; X, Y \in \mathbb{N}$

Covering domino means replacing two adjacent horizontally or vertically 0 by 1. Example:

```
00 => 11
01    01

or

00 => 10
01    11
```

The rectangle covered with a dominoes if in the end it will only consist of 1.

[Barry Cipra gave the correct answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/632520/119539), but it is not complete.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you define "covered with a domino"? In my intuitive understading, the 7th case and 10th case (diagonal 1s) are covered with dominoes. But unless you define it explicitly one can't be sure about it.

Comment: Covering domino means replacing two adjacent 0 horizontally or vertically by 1.

Comment: Ok so you have a partially occupied area, and you want to complete the occupancy using 2x1 rectangles. The confusion arises because usually when one talks about bi-valued boards and domino pieces, it's normally related to coloring and to cover the board matching the colors. You should edit your question by explaining it better.

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimer_model.

Comment: The OP is interested in whether there is any covering, not in the number of them. In any case, from the wikipedia article, it seems a very hard problem.

Comment: I need to determine how many rectangles $2^{XY}$ can be covered by rectangles 1×2 completely without overlaps.

Comment: That pluses and minuses mean match with the condition. 'rectangles $2^{XY}$' - all variants of rectangles.

I made a mistake in the name.

Comment: Why do I feel like this question is actually a problem in some programming contest? You know, the restrictions on $X$ and $Y$ would be quite strange otherwise...

Comment: This problem can be solved by programming?

Comment: There are some obstructions: if we take a $n\times n$ chessboard with the usual black&white coloring and remove some squares, in order to have a domino-tiling of the remaining part we need that the number of black squares equals the number of white squares and no "isolated" squares are left.

Comment: Unfortunately, this conditions are not sufficient to give the existence of a domino-tiling, as we can see by removing in a usual chessboard the $a,c,e,g$-files and the $b1,d8,f1,h8$ squares.

Comment: Maybe the condition that every connected component of the residual chessboard has the same number of black and white squares is sufficient.

Comment: No, this is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a long comment than an answer, but I hope it helps.  If I understand the OP's question correctly, the problem can be described this way:  Cover the squares of an $m\times n$ chessboard completely with coins and dominoes.  Then *remove* the dominoes and consider only the pattern of coins.  As a function of $m$ and $n$, how many different such patterns are possible?

Call this function $P(m,n)$.  The OP's example shows that $P(2,2)=6$.  It's easy to see that the sequence $P(1,n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence $1,2,3,5,8,\dots$.  For $m=2$, I get $P(2,n)=2\cdot3^{n-1}$ in general, from the following recursion:

$$\begin{align}
P(2,n)&=2P(2,n-1)+2Q(2,n-1)\\
Q(2,n)&=P(2,n-1)+Q(2,n-1)\\
\end{align}$$

with $P(2,1)=2$ and $Q(2,1)=1$.  The sequence $Q(2,n)$ counts the number of patterns with a coin in the lower right hand corner.  I hope someone will doublecheck this.

Comment: That's right! I came to this earlier, but I can not continue for $m = 3, 4, 5, 6 $

Comment: For $m=3$, may be a sequence is 3, 18, 98, ... My methods are based on intuition, for the correct solution I can not find ideas.